# Popper.js tooltip placement for absolute position div (bootstrap)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popper.js

I am trying to create a 'info' icon in the top right of a div that is already full (with a chartist.js chart). To do this I'm using an absolute positioned div with the span inside of it.

```
<div class="position-absolute right-0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Example Text">
    <span class="mt-2 fas fa-info-circle u-icon"></span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this causes the tooltip placement (and more importantly the hover area), to be lower than the actual icon.

[image]

What's the best practice in regards to adding an info icon on top of an already full div with bootstrap/HTML/CSS, and more specifically, what is the best/easiest way to fix this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Put the tooltip in the span:

```
<div class="position-absolute right-0">
    <span class="mt-2 fas fa-info-circle u-icon"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-original-title="Example Text"></span>
</div>
```